# Respect rbenv when running commands over ssh

Tags: ruby, ssh, rbenv

I have a headless Ubuntu 18.04 VM where I'm installing a Rails application on top of rbenv.

I want to be able to automate some administrative operations so I can run them locally and have my script execute the commands over ssh.  However when I do this, I get the system ruby instead of the rbenv ruby.  If I ssh directly to the box, then I get the correct rbenv ruby.

Example:

```sh
ubuntu:~$ cat show-ruby.sh
which ruby
ruby --version
ubuntu:~$ bash show-ruby.sh
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/ruby
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
```

```sh
laptop:~$ ssh ubuntu 'bash show-ruby.sh'
/usr/bin/ruby
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

rbenv is initialized in my `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

So I tried adding `source ~/.bashrc` to the top of my `show-ruby.sh` test script but it doesn't make a difference.  Any ideas how I can force my remotely executed scripts to respect my rbenv-installed ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rbenv triggers from an initialization installed in `.bashrc`.  However, that initialization only occurs for an interactive shell.  You can force a bash shell to be interactive with the `-i` flag:

```sh
laptop:~$ ssh ubuntu 'bash -i show-ruby.sh'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/ruby
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a .ruby-version file with the needed ruby version and rbenv will automatically set the ruby version

```
[current] > cat .ruby-version
2.4.6
[current] > rbenv version
2.4.6 (set by .ruby-version)
```

Comment: The problem is rbenv doesn't even get invoked, that's why it's returning the system ruby at `/usr/bin/ruby`